# Wordpress query category

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I face a strange problem. I would like to only show posts from category 7. But with the following code it does not show me anything:

```
$featured = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tours', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'id', 'cat' => 7));
                if($featured->have_posts()) {
                    while($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
                        echo the_title();
                    endwhile;
                }
```

I am also using this:

```
$featured = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tours', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'id', 'category__in' => 7));
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: beside the if statement from the first block of code, what's the diff with your $featured from the first to the second?

Comment: Remove post_type and check once because it's working fine here.If it's working,issue is not with cat

Comment: but @BhumiShah Post type is important an than i create its taxaonomy, from where i want to call data

Comment: Yes i understand,I  just want to confirm that issue is with post_type so if yes, i can go in that direction for solution

Comment: Remove echo in the_title();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Nadeem Try this i hope u will find your answer

```
   $featured = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'tours',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tours_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array(7),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
```

Comment: Thanax Deemi this is very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after calling `$featured = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tours', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'id', 'cat' => 7));`

call `echo $featured->found_posts` and find out, whether there are posts in your query

Comment: That means, you have a issue in your query. What would I do? I would put into the WP_Query object only `cat => 7` parameter, eventually another category, then check the number of posts in `WP_Query::found_posts`; then subsequently add the other parameters and watch, which parameter make the query to return zero

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 $args=array(
                      'category__in' => array('7'),
                      'post_type' => 'tours',
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'posts_per_page' => -1,
                      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
                    );
 $featured = new WP_Query($args);
 if($featured->have_posts()) {
                while($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
                    echo the_title();
                endwhile;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $featured = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'tours', 'cat' => 7, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'id', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ));
    if($featured->have_posts()) {
      while ($featured->have_posts()) : $featured->the_post();
        the_title();
      endwhile;
    }
```